# Lite-Javascript Gallery - Can I position the img absolutely in relationship to the <li>s?

Tags: javascript, css, image-gallery

I have a lite-javascript run image gallery.  The javascript grabs each `<img>` element in the list and places it as a background in the parent `<li>` element. Then the CSS styles the thumbnails as small blocks with a defined height/width. A click-event for each `<li>` object toggles its child’s `<img>` element’s visibility and adds an “active” class name to the `<li>`. Using CSS, I'm trying to place the `<img>` absolutely to make it appear at the same position for each thumb, but it's moving in relation to the thumbs.

Here's the CSS:

```
#jgal li {
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:solid #999 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    margin-bottom:14px;
    margin-right:14px;
    opacity:0.5;
}

#jgal li img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:210px;
    display:none;
}
```

And the site: http://www.erisdesigns.net

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks Marcel.  Heh, I'm gonna have to buy you lunch pretty soon!

Comment: Haha, nice! But the main point: do you get it? Those tags are eaten by this site, so you should enclose them within [backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/how-to-disable-markdown-feature/28167#28167). And don't forget to use *@user-name* in your comments, so we get [notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I do, I do!  And I appreciate the tutelage.  Thanks!

Comment: This title is a little confusing, do you want the `<img>` relative to the `<li>` or to some other parent container like `#jgal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:absolute` elements base their positioning to the closest parent element with `position:relative`

If you want the image to be relative to the `<li>`'s position, all you should need to do is add `position:relative;` to the `#jgal li`.

If you want to position it relative to `#jgal`, you can apply the `position:relative` there instead, and make sure the `#jgal li` is `position:static` (which is default, unless you are overriding it somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

if you want the `<img>` to appear at the same position:

```
#jgal {
  list-style: none outside;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

#jgal li {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 3px solid #999999;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 14px 14px 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: static;   // Need to specify static since you have style li { position: relative; } inside another css file
  width: 60px;
}

#jgal li img {
  border: medium none;
  display: none;
  left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

If you want `img` to be shown near the thumb - change position: static; to position: relative; for  #jgal li {

Comment: Yep that's what I was missing.  Appreciate the help!